# Double Free error with AddressSanitizer GCC 4.8

Tags: c++, gcc, atomic, noexcept, address-sanitizer

Consider the following toy program(`prog.cpp`):

```
class A {
public:
    vector<int> vec;
    A() noexcept {}
    A(vector<int> s) : vec(s) {}
};

class B {

private:
    vector<atomic<A>> a_table;

public:
    B(int capacity) : a_table(capacity) {}

    void update(int index) {
        A newValue(vector<int>(10,1));
        a_table[index].store(newValue);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
B b(5);
b.update(2);
return 0;
}
```

This when compiled normally (`g++ prog.cpp -latomic`), works fine. But when compiled as `g++ -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer prog.cpp -latomic` produces Double Free error when executed. A program based on similar lines as above has to be used in a multi-threaded application, where even the normal compilation is producing Double Free error. I read up Rule of Three/Five, which is generally referred to in case of Double Free, and various other documentations but nothing worked.

Also, removing `noexcept` specifier from the `class A`'s default constructor produces this strange error, which also I would like to know about.

```
error: function ‘std::atomic<_Tp>::atomic() [with _Tp = A]’ defaulted on its first declaration with an exception-specification that differs from the implicit declaration ‘std::atomic<A>::atomic()’
   atomic() noexcept = default;
   ^
```

Comment: gcc 6.2.1 produces the following diagnostic: "In instantiation of ‘struct std::atomic<A>/static assertion failed: std::atomic requires a trivially copyable type".

Comment: ^^ [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/671979c7d41cc42b)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I roughly got what you are saying, but how is Double Free related to this?

Comment: @ibrahim5253 It isn't. May be it's you to ask yourself why?

Comment: @Eichhörnchen Yes. But I am able to compile the code, Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 5):

`std::atomic` requires a [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) type, which your `A` is not, because its member of type `vector<int>` (e.g.) is not trivially copy constructible.

[GCC only detects a violation of that requirement since version 5.0.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63322)

The fact that older gcc versions compile the code does not mean that it is valid.

Comment: So the issue here would be that the vector is being trivial-copied instead of properly copy-constructor-copied, so multiple vectors have pointers to the same heap memory?

Comment: @ruakh Presumably. I have not looked at the implementation of std::atomic in libstdc++, but I was able to reproduce the double-free and the developers probably assumed that memcpy or similar is always ok in this case.

Comment: @Eichhörnchen So what is the workaround? All I want is a *container* in `A`, so are there any trivially copyable ones?

Comment: @ibrahim5253 Except for arrays maybe you cannot have any container in an std::atomic. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Eichhörnchen How is even an array possible? Won't I be required to write my custom copy ctor, assignment, and destructor (The Big Three) when using dynamically allocated array (as size will be available at run-time), making the class again non-trivial?

Comment: @ibrahim5253 Yes, I meant static arrays, i.e. `std::array`, actually. There is no way to have dynamic allocation in there.

Comment: @ibrahim5253: I have some thoughts about how you can do what you want. If you open a question about it, please post a link here to let me know. :-)